# renaming columns dynamically

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I am using MS ACCESS 2007. I have the following query :-

```
Select 
    [table1.column1] as [week 1], 
    [table1.column2] as [week 2], 
    [table1.column3] as [week 3] 
FROM [table1];
```

I have a master table having two columns which contains an `id` (values are 1,2,3) and `names` (values are column1_name, column2_name, column3_name)

Is it possible to change column name from the master table?

I want `[table1.column1]` heading to be column1_name and so on.

Comment: I have given a very simplified version of my query. My database has over 400 queries and 90 reports are to be generated using them. So I need to know how to rename columns using querying

Comment: 1) have you considered using a numbers or tally table (google it) for dates, and 2) maybe pivot the results - would it be easier to get the data as rows per date instead of columns?

Comment: Client requirements state that they want this in the above mentioned format only

Comment: Where do you want to get the column names from?  Do you want to store them in a table or enter them manually at runtime?

Comment: Also, if you change alias the columns in your queries, all your reports will break because they won't be able to find their source fields.

Answer (score 1):

Why not give column alias in query like

```
SELECT [table1.column1] AS column1_name , [table1.column2] AS column2_name, 
       [table1.column3] AS column3_name 
FROM MASTERTABLE
```

Comment: The problem is that I don't want to HARDCODE my table names. The actual queries I am using generate different columns each representing different weeks. Say column1 is from week-16, column 2 from week-19 and so on. so hardcoding is out

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should play with the Pivot Table View ... that might do what you want.